# how to use eband_local_planner with navigation?

Tags: ros, navigation, eband-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I installed eband_local_planner  package by `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-eband-local-planner` . But when i try to use it with navigation ,the "base_local_planner " param of   move_base  does not changed   when i  launch the corresponding launch  file.And  in the terminal , no error  occurred！！！

In the move_base node ,i set
`<rosparam file="$(find rbx1_nav)/config/fake/eband_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />`  and
`<param name="base_local_planer" value="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS" />`
when using `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core`,it shows me that  eband_local_planner   is  one of  the plugins of nav_core, and when i use `roscd   eband_local_planner`,i also can find  it   in  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/eband_local_planner".

how  should  i do to  configure eband_local_planner with   navigation  correctively  ?  Thanks   a lot ^-^

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242614/how-to--use-eband_local_planner--with--navigation-?/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2016-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks all,  i find  why  this happen .  Spelling mistake ： `param name="base_local_planer"`   ,should be `param name="base_local_planner"`.

---

Originally posted by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) with karma: 252 on 2016-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0